# Are there any CSS classes for the wordpress colours?

Tags: css, color-picker

Are there any CSS classes for the wordpress colours: https://make.wordpress.org/design/handbook/design-guide/foundations/colors/

For instance, classes like these from the Twenty Seventeen Theme:

```
.has-text-color .has-background .has-very-dark-gray-color .has-very-light-gray-background-color
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The only styles that WordPress itself loads on the front-end is `/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css`, and this stylesheet doesn't include any such classes or colours. All other styles are the responsibility of the theme.

So if you want to know if a specific theme has such classes you would need to ask the author, however I don't know any reason why anyone would include the WordPress brand colours in their theme.